# Controller class not found laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am new to laravel and I tried to post the values from view to controller. But I am not able to get through as i get error saying 
`FatalErrorException in routes.php line 26: Class 'registration' not found` while submitting the form

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/register', function(){
return view('register');
});

Route::post('/register_action', function()
{
     $values = registration::store();
});
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\model\registration as register_model

class registration extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        echo 'hello';
        register_model::saveFormData();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'register_action')) !!}
        <p>Name : {!! Form::text('name') !!}</p>
        <p>Email : {!! Form::text('email') !!}</p>
        <p>Password : {!! Form::password('password') !!}</p>
        <p>Confirm Password : {!! Form::password('cpassword') !!}</p>
        <p>{!! Form::submit('Submit') !!}</p>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to solve the issue and to get the post values in controller. Thanks

Comment: Please don't use closures like this. send it to the controller, and work from there. and by the way, you forgot a `;` in your last namespace.

Comment: You should capitalize name of your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use controller like this:

```
$values = registration::store();
```

Use need to change in your route.

```
Route::post('/register_action', 'registration@store');
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to call the controller methods in routes (which is a bad idea) you could add a use statement

`use App\Http\Controllers\registration;`

but it would still give you an error because you're calling a non static method statically, so you're best choice would be @Alexey Mezenin [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40910505/2870548)

Answer (score 0):

The route should look like this:

```
Route::post('/register_action', 'registration@store');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing